# Zabbix - check not supported by agent

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

A check that looks pretty standard fails on the zabbix agent. The check is `not supported` on the web interface. Checking via console does that too:

```
% zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -p 10050 -k "kernel.maxproc"
ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED
```

There is no note in the zabbix-agent log about that check. What can I do to debug / fix it?

With `Debug=5` in zabbix_agentd I get only:

```
 12172:20110320:225114 Processing request.
 12172:20110320:225114 In check_security()
 12172:20110320:225114 Requested [kernel.maxproc]
 12172:20110320:225114 Sending back [ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED]
```

Answer (score 1):

quite important facts are missing - for example, zabbix agent version and the operating system where it is installed.

best guess based on available information - either this is some more exotic platform where these checks are genuinely not supported (see http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/items#supported_by_platform), or a security solution like grsecurity, selinux or apparmor prevents the agent from reading that data.

Comment: The system is stock Debian 6.0, the agent is Zabbix Agent v1.8.2. There is no grsec / security module running. Couldn't find any relevant notes on the page either.

Comment: question says "The check is system.cpu.util[,wait,avg1]", but example shows "kernel.maxproc" - so which is working and which is not ?

Comment: maxproc - must've been a silly copy&paste mistake